Powerline Network Adapter crashes Orbi Hub
I use an Orbi extender hub as the location where a netgear power line carrier device plugs into the orbi using a Cat5 wire 10Base T connector. When the Orbi hub and PLC device are both plugged in, all works OK for 1-2 days. Then the Orbi app shows the PLC device is in error mode, and the Orbi hub is crashed, and has to be power cycled to come back on line.
It seems the PLC device crashes the orbi: both are at an incovenient garage location: the PLC allows network access to an orchard well pump about 200 yards from the Orbi / PLC complex.
Tried a different PLC device and a different wire connecting the PLC to the Orbi. The orbi hub will not freeze for sometimes several days AFTER the orbi app says the PLC device is no longer connected. And I really need to be able to control the orchard pump conveniently this way: running a new 200 yard network cable is prohibitive given the digging required.
